# Dual boot Windows 10 over Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I am currently using Ubuntu 14.04 and use it as my primary OS. I would like to dual boot over Ubuntu. Although I have read that it is preferable to do the other way round, still, I need to dual boot Windows 10 over Ubuntu.

I have read of issues with the grub and need to avoid those kind of problems.

Please provide me with a step by step solution considering that I have no experience of dual booting operating systems.

EDIT: I have tried to create a partition using GParted but have failed to do so. My drive with 912 GB cannot be resized. [Here is the](https://i.imgsafe.org/daf3d89.png) screenshot.

Comment: Check this out http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu

Comment: @Alexiy: Cannot create a new partition using GParted. Here are the screenshots. https://i.imgsafe.org/2d2f649.png and https://i.imgsafe.org/47a0d11.png. Please tell me what do I do next?

Comment: As Joao wrote, you should try do that from live session.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in a similar predicament recently, and the solution I found was to load GParted from a usb drive:

http://gparted.org/liveusb.php

You can also use a cd to do so. Remember to go into the BIOS of your pc and set it to boot from the desired usb/optical drive first.

In the screenshot you anexed the drive can't be partitioned because it is in use. By loading GParted before the OS you will be able to resize it at will.

I hope that helps, good luck.